# How to insert a nil_uuid in Postgres, using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Using Python and SQLAlchemy, is it possible to insert None / NIL_UUID / NULL value in a Postgresql foreign key column that links to a primary key, both stored as UUID ?

- `None` returns `column none does not exist` :

```
statement = "INSERT INTO tb_person (pk_person, first_name, last_name, fk_person_parent) VALUES ('9ce131...985
fea06', 'John', 'Doe', None)"
parameters = {}, context = <sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2.PGExecutionContext_psycopg2 object at 0x7fbff5ea2730>

    def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
>       cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
E       psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "none" does not exist
E       LINE 1: '9ce131...985','John', 'Doe', None)
E                                             ^
E       HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "tb_person.last_name".

../../.local/share/virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:593: UndefinedColumn
```

- a `NIL_UUID` (i.e. a valid UUID formed with 0s) returns `psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation`:

```
E       psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation: insert or update on table "tb_person" violates foreign key constrain
t "tb_person_fk_person_parent_fkey"
E       DETAIL:  Key (fk_person_parent)=(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) is not present in table "tb_person
".
```

**MORE DETAILS**

I use SQLAlchemy classical mapping (SQLAlchemy Core), my table is defined like this :

```
tb_person = Table(
    "tb_person",
    metadata,
    Column(
        "pk_person",
        UUID(as_uuid=True), 
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        unique=True,
        nullable=False
    ),
    Column("first_name", String(255)),
    Column("last_name", String(255)),
    Column(
        "fk_person_parent", UUID(as_uuid=True),
        ForeignKey("tb_person.pk_person"),
        nullable=True
    )
)
```

The mapper is defined like this :

```
    client_mapper = mapper(
        domain.model.Person,
        tb_person,
        properties={
            "child": relationship(domain.model.Person),
        },
    )
```

The unit test works well when inserting a UUID that already exists in the database in the pk_person field.

Comment: It is possible to `INSERT` a `NULL` value in the `FOREIGN KEY` field. Your `NIL_UUID` value is not `NULL` though so it will need an entry in the `PRIMARY KEY` in the referenced table.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks, you coined my question in shorter terms that I have done. How can I insert NULL in an UUID field, when neither None nor NIL_UUID work ?

Comment: You are not actually passing in `None`, instead you are passing in "None" which is being seen as a column name.  If `fk_person_parent` allows `NULL` then just do not include that field in the `INSERT` and `NULL` will be set for that value.  You really should be using parameters to pass the values in, then `None` would be properly adapted to `NULL` on `INSERT`.

Comment: From psycopg2 traceback, the statement reads "INSERT INTO tb_person (pk_person, first_name, last_name, fk_person_parent) VALUES ('9ce131...985fea06', 'John', 'Doe', None)" - it was inserted as None (and not "None") in the query, but thanks I will try again using parameters.

Comment: Yes but as the error, `psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "none" does not exist`, shows since it was in a string it got double  quoted and was mistaken for an identifier(a column in this case). Which is also why it got down cased.

Comment: Actually I got that wrong, it was in the bigger string unquoted and was taken for an identifier. Since it was not quoted it got down cased to match a column name. That column name was not found and the name was double quoted in the error message as an identifier name.

Answer (score 0):

I was using raw SQL, and as suggested by @AdrianKlaver it is much preferable to use params - it fixes the problem.

```
# In the context of this unit test,
# we have to handle UUID generation here
uuid_1 = uuid.uuid4()
uuid_2 = uuid.uuid4()
uuid_3 = uuid.uuid4()

session.execute(
"""
INSERT INTO tb_person
(pk_person, first_name, last_name, fk_parent_person) 
VALUES
(:uuid_1, 'John', 'Doe', :uuid_none),
(:uuid_2, 'Jean', 'Dupont', :uuid_none)
(:uuid_3, 'Baby', 'Doe', :uuid_1)
""",
 {"uuid_1": uuid_1, "uuid_2", "uuid_3": uuid_3, ":uuid_none": None}
)
```

It effectively translates to NULL in the query.